# animating scrollTo with overflow text

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, overflow

Hi I am having some issues with getting some div elements to scroll into view from an overflow auto in a sperate div to the indexing links (probably not explained that too well!) Ideally I would like this to animate smoothly

I tried a few techniques using offset and position, however they seemed erratic, I wondered what the best way of doing this would be, I am using jquery  if that helps

example code:

http://jsbin.com/ifefix/11/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/N5bWm/2/

Here's a summary:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="one">1</div>
        <div id="two">2</div>
        <div id="three">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// bind an action to the click event on your links
$("ul > li > a").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the "block" offset from the top of the #container div (and add to it the actual scroll of the div)
    var scrollto = $($(this).attr("href")).position().top + $("#container").scrollTop();

    // stop previous non-ended animations, and scroll smoothly to the new "block"
    $("#container").stop(true).animate({ scrollTop: scrollto }, 1000);
});
```

**CSS:**

The only property that matters is `position: relative` for `#container`, to get accurate values from `$().position()`.

Comment: Thanks dude, that is exactly what I needed, I was doing something very similar but this is spot on, thanks again